# Break/explode String in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

can some 1 tell how to break this sort of String in smarty what i want is "1" as price and "dollar" as currency type.

```
"1|dollar"
```

please reply.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
{assign var=someVar value="|"|explode:"1|dollar"}
```

and then access "1" and "dollar" through 0 and 1 indexes of the "someVar" variable like below,

`{$somevar[0]}` and `{$somevar[1]}`

Comment: thx for answer. I tried that approach when i dumped the $somevar i can only get "1" nothing more. Any idea?

Comment: How did you try to access the "1" and "dollar"?

Comment: {$somevar[0]} and {$somevar[1]}

Comment: i also tried this {print_r|$somevar} this actually displays "1"

Comment: {assign var=someVar1 value= "1|dollar"}                
                {assign var=someVar value="|"|explode:$somevar1}
                
                {$somevar[0]}
                {$somevar[1]}

Comment: Isn't smarty case sensetive? You should write {$someVar[0]}. Also try with {$someVar.0} ... sorry my smarty knowledge is a bit rusty :)